# appendRow() adds blank row in google sheets (app script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've setup a google app script that would be triggered from an external system. This script would fetch the details from the third party system and add them to google sheet row.

```
function doPost(request) {

  try{
  var jsonString = request.postData.getDataAsString(); //get the request from KF as JSON String
  setLog("\n postData*********************"+jsonString+"************************************* \n");

 setLog("before the row append");

 ss.appendRow([jsonString["Name"], jsonString["Age"], jsonString["Contact"]]);


  setLog("After the row append");
    
  var returnJson = '{"status": "success"}'; 
  //used to send the return value to the calling function

  setLog("/n returnJson****************************"+returnJson+"************************************* /n")
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(returnJson).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 }
```

There's absolutely no errors or warnings, but somehow it keeps adding the blank rows into the sheet.

Note: setLog() is a function where I print the values into google doc for debugging.

Comment: Try to add the condition like: `if (jsonString["Name"] != '') {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maybe the reason your script is not working has to do with the value of `jsonString`.

I could not find any reference to `request.postData.getDataAsString()` inside GAS Documentation, so maybe you are trying to call a method on an object which does not support it, which would **not** raise an Error, but would return `undefined`.

One quick way to debug this would be to LOG the value (using your custom function or `Logger.log(jsonString)`) BEFORE you call `.appendRow()`. Then, you can verify if your variable has the value you expect it to have.

On the other hand, my suggestion is to use this method:

```
var jsonString = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents) //Gets the content of your request, then parses it
```

This method is present in the Documentation, and has been consistently working on all of my projects.

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm. It was returning Undefined and made the changes as per your suggestions

Comment: @BharathKumar It was a pleasure to help you, can you mark my answer as "accepted" please? Wish you luck on your next projects!

Comment: Sure, I have already marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sort the coulmns with google app script. Write this code after `ss.appendRow`. The column will be sorted and all blank rows gets down.

```
// Sorts the sheet by the first column, ascending
ss.sort(1)
```

or if errors try this one also

```
var fl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = fl.getSheets()[0];
fl.sort(1)
```